# How to connect between ASP.NET page and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to put current time on ASP.NET page. How can i get the control ID from Javascript? I'm using C# ASP.NET

On my Form

```
<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
       <span id="clock">&nbsp;</span>
   </form>
</body>
```

Javascript Function

```
function updateClock ( )
{
   document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ShowTime() {
   var dt = new Date();
   document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").value = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
   window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
 }  
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // a startup script to put everything in motion
    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
</script>
```

***If you are using normal web form then it can also be called on Body onload event. If you are using MasterPage then it can be called within ContentTemplate at the end after all the controls have been rendered.***

Comment: "<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>" This one is what i wanted to know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use JavaScript for displaying current time on the page.

Here is the link :-
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Answer (score 0):

Write function like this

```
 function updateClock ( )
 {
   document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = currentTimeString;
 }
```